# android ClassCastException error "button can't be cast as edittext"

Tags: android

My `Activity_main.xml`

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/MyButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="@string/button" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/PasswordText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/PasswordText"
    android:inputType="textPassword" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/UsernameText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/UsernameText" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

Java File `MainAcivity.java`

```
package com.example.buttonclicktutorial;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
    EditText name;
    EditText pass;
    Button login;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.UsernameText);
        pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.PasswordText);
        login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.MyButton);
        login.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                 NewActivity.class);
         startActivity(myIntent);

    }

}
```

When I am running the app I am getting `ClassCastException`

```
10-08 13:28:11.970: E/AndroidRuntime(6674): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-08 13:28:11.970: E/AndroidRuntime(6674): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.buttonclicktutorial/com.example.buttonclicktutorial.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Button cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText
10-08 13:28:11.970: E/AndroidRuntime(6674):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1978)
10-08 13:28:11.970: E/AndroidRuntime(6674):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2003)
10-08 13:28:11.970: E/AndroidRuntime(6674):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
10-08 13:28:11.970: E/AndroidRuntime(6674):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1169)
10-08 13:28:11.970: E/AndroidRuntime(6674):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-08 13:28:11.970: E/AndroidRuntime(6674):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-08 13:28:11.970: E/AndroidRuntime(6674):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4446)
10-08 13:28:11.970: E/AndroidRuntime(6674):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-08 13:28:11.970: E/AndroidRuntime(6674):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-08 13:28:11.970: E/AndroidRuntime(6674):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
10-08 13:28:11.970: E/AndroidRuntime(6674):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
10-08 13:28:11.970: E/AndroidRuntime(6674):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-08 13:28:11.970: E/AndroidRuntime(6674): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Button cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText
10-08 13:28:11.970: E/AndroidRuntime(6674):     at com.example.buttonclicktutorial.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20)
10-08 13:28:11.970: E/AndroidRuntime(6674):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
10-08 13:28:11.970: E/AndroidRuntime(6674):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
10-08 13:28:11.970: E/AndroidRuntime(6674):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1942)
10-08 13:28:11.970: E/AndroidRuntime(6674):     ... 11 more
```

As far as I understand , the I am not casting Button as an edittext. I am not sure , why I am getting this error.

Comment: That's a funny one. Have you tried cleaning the project and trying again?

Comment: And which line is `MainActivity.java:20`?

Comment: `login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.MyButton);`

Comment: @misguided have you tried a clean and rebuild like suggested

Comment: I did ,It has fixed the issue. I assumed I must have gone wrong somewhere rather than it being a eclipse issue ;) @szymon mate , can you post that as an answer, I'll accept the same.

Comment: Great. I did post it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a funny one.

Have you tried cleaning the project and trying again? It often helps in such situations - the resource files (ID's) get out of order.

Comment: This generally happens most of the times while using eclipse(dont know about other editors though), when you change the xmls repeatedly and simply run the app, it happens that when the app runs references to other elements are not updated. This answer really helps.

Answer (score 1):

Just clean your project and rebuild it.
This often occurs after you edit or refactor some of your xml layout files.
The Auto generated resource ids are in a mess. Editor's id becomes Button's.

Comment: @Mate upped you answer. Szymon had given the solution earlier , so have to accept his answer.